# Optimized screen capture directly from device context

Tags: windows, visual-c++, screenshot, gdi

I've managed to get a buffer pointer from a Bitmap object as follows:

```
hDesktopWnd=GetDesktopWindow();
hDesktopDC=GetDC(hDesktopWnd);

  // Get Screen Dimensions 

  int         nWidth=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
  int         nHeight=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

  CImage objCImg;
  objCImg.Create( nWidth, nHeight, 24, BI_RGB);

   HDC hdcMemDC = objCImg.GetDC();

   if(!BitBlt(hdcMemDC,0,0,nWidth, nHeight,hDesktopDC, 0,0,SRCCOPY))
    {
        printf("Error during Bitblt");
    }

   unsigned char* pData = (unsigned char*)objCImg.GetBits();
```

I can modify the image using this pData.

I am trying to optimize screen capture timing, but even though this operation contains only one **BitBlt**, still this operation is taking 94ms on my PC. While

```
// Get the Desktop windows handle and device context
hDesktopWnd=GetDesktopWindow();
hDesktopDC=GetDC(hDesktopWnd);

// Get the handle to the existing DC and create a bitmap file object    
HDC         hBmpFileDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
HBITMAP     hBmpFileBitmap=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC,nWidth,nHeight);

//    Assign the object in Memory DC to the bitmap and perform a bitblt
  SelectObject(hBmpFileDC,hBmpFileBitmap);
  BitBlt(hBmpFileDC,0,0,nWidth,nHeight,hDesktopDC,0,0,SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);

  pBuf=malloc(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage); // Size of Image
  GetDIBits(hdc,hBitmap,0,bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight,pBuf,&bmpInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

This operation has one **BitBlt** and one Memory Copy operation in **GetDIBits** still this total operation is taking 46 ms on my PC.

Can someone please clarify this discrepancy in the two BitBlt operation and why the bitblt is taking more time when the DC is not derived as a compatible DC (CreateCompatibleDC) in the first case because as per my understanding BitBlt is almost similar to a **memcpy** operation.

Inturn I would also like to ask is there any way to access the image buffer pointer directly from the hdc. 
which means can get buffer pointer to the image directly from the HDC

```
hDesktopWnd=GetDesktopWindow();
hDesktopDC=GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
// Now derive buffer from this **hDesktopDC**
```

I've also asked the same question before: [Unable to access buffer data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228157/unable-to-access-buffer-data-after-screen-capture)

Also, can someone pls comment if windows allows such type of data handling?